# What is the short key to delete the whole row in Excel 2007 without using mouse?

Tags: excel, mouse

I am trying to find the short key for deleting the entire row in Excel 2007 without taking help of mouse.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting this question? What were the results.

Comment: yes, i have searched on internet but could not find a perfect solution.

Comment: Shift + Spacebar then Ctrl + -

Comment: Ok. If you do not want your question further downgraded. Describe your problem in more detail e.g. why the default Excel shortcut does not suit you, what is the desired solution and what effort have you made to reach that solution so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

```
Ctrl+-  == Deletes Rows, Columns, or Cells Depends on selection
```

You should first select the entire row.

For this you can use <kbd>Home</kbd> then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrorw</kbd>.

OR

You can just click on the row number to select entire row.

After selecting the entire row, If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> then entire row will be deleted.